# PusherSwift Can't establish a websocket connection

Tags: ios, swift, websocket, pusherswift

I'm trying to connect to a socket from my own application, when I call `pusher.connect()`, the following is displayed in the console:

```
2024-01-23 13:05:30.963189+0500 pusher_test[64299:2525981] [] nw_protocol_copy_ws_definition_block_invoke [C1:1] nw_ws_validate_server_response
2024-01-23 13:05:30.964076+0500 pusher_test[64299:2525981] [connection] nw_read_request_report [C1] Receive failed with error "Software caused connection abort"
```

[image]

This is my code test harness:

```swift
class AuthRequestBuilder: AuthRequestBuilderProtocol {
    func requestFor(socketID: String, channelName: String) -> URLRequest? {
        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: authPath)!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.addValue("Bearer "+token, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
        return request
    }
}

let optionsWithEndpoint = PusherClientOptions(
    authMethod: AuthMethod.authRequestBuilder(authRequestBuilder: AuthRequestBuilder()),
    host:.host(host),
    port:6001,
    useTLS: false
)
pusher = Pusher(key: "pusher_app_key", options: optionsWithEndpoint)

pusher.connect()

let myPresenceChannel = pusher.subscribeToPresenceChannel(channelName: "presence-online")
```

I typically write in Flutter and I am new to Swift.

Xcode version: 14.3.1.
Swift version: swift-driver version: 1.75.2 Apple Swift version 5.8.1 (swiftlang-5.8.0.124.5 clang-1403.0.22.11.100)

I tested it on the iOS simulator, but the error persists on a real device.